# Pruebas Unitarias en un Servicio Web API

Tags: c#, webservice

Estoy investigando sobre como realizar pruebas unitarias para un servicio **Web API**.
Resulta que ya tengo el método creado y ya se montar medianamente bien la prueba unitaria, pero cuando quiero devolver el resultado de un método del servicio, me da error de incompatibilidad, por que el tipo que devuelve el servicio es `HTTPResponse` y en el test no se como podría recogerlo.

Este es el error que me da:

> Error CS0029  No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo
>   'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage' en
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'   SvcWebAPI_TEST  D:\Users\jtp\Source\Workspace\SYS\I+D+i\SvcWebAPI\SvcWebAPI_TEST\CambioZonatestController.cs

Comment: podrias poner el codigo donde detectas este problema ? recuerda que puedes agregar al test la referencia a la libreria System.Net para usar el HttpResponseMessage

Comment: Este es el método, la ultima linea es la que me da el error.

`[TestMethod]
        public void ZonasDisponiblesTest_TerminalAlmacen()
        {
            List<View_CU_SGM> listaSGM = new List<View_CU_SGM>();

            listaSGM = cambioZonaTest.ZonasDisponibles(19);
            
        }`

Comment: pero porque asignas el resultado de ZonasDisponibles() a un List<View_CU_SGM> ? sabes que ese metodo retorna una lista, esta claro por el mensaje que no

Comment: ZonasDisponibles() devuelve un HttpResponseMessage, pero en ese retorno se encuentra una lista de View_CU_SGM, he utilizado el HttpResponseMessage para recoger el resultado y ya me funciona. 
Muchas gracias @LeandroTuttini , soy nuevo en esto y me estaba costando un poco.